# How to return Multiple dataset for multiple stored procedures in .net

Tags: sql, asp.net

This is my code:

```csharp
this.SelectQuery = "stp_customer_master";
this.SelectParameter = new SqlParameter[4];

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SelectParameter[0] = new SqlParameter();
SelectParameter[0].ParameterName = "@Op4";
SelectParameter[0].Value = "SELECT_TOTAL_CUSTOMER";

SelectParameter[1] = new SqlParameter();
SelectParameter[1].ParameterName = "@Op5";
SelectParameter[1].Value = "SELECT_TOTAL_CUSTOMER_HIGH_PRIORITY";

SelectParameter[2] = new SqlParameter();
SelectParameter[2].ParameterName = "@Op6";
SelectParameter[2].Value = "SELECT_TOTAL_CUSTOMER_MEDIUM_PRIORITY";

SelectParameter[3] = new SqlParameter();
SelectParameter[3].ParameterName = "@Op7";
SelectParameter[3].Value = "SELECT_TOTAL_CUSTOMER_LOW_PRIORITY";

res = this.GetDataSet;
```

Here I will get result in `res = this.GetDataset` for all in one result
I want separate results for all 4 stored procedures.

What is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection("Connectionstring");
SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand();
SqlDataAdapter da=new SqlDataAdapter();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
cmd = new SqlCommand("getdata", con); //"getdata"- name of your stored procedure 
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;    
da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(ds);
con.Close();
```

After this you can access the tables in dataset like this

```
ds.Tables[0]
ds.Tables[1]
```

in your case you can create common function which accepts the stored procedure name as parameter and returns the dataset for that stored procedure.

Comment: I have multiple store procedure and each have dataset then how i return all that dataset  individually of all store procedures?